# Compare input double value with several known values

Tags: java, if-statement

I am reading numeric values from a CSV file. I want to compare those values with other values known in advance (`x`, `y` and `z` in the below code, where it is known that `x < y < z`). But I'm having trouble figuring out how to compare any given value to `x`, `y` and `z` and acting on the result.

```
public HashMap<String , Double> ReadCVS() {
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String line = "";
    String cvsSplitBy = ",";
    double x = 7.33;
    double y = 12.33;
    double z = 20.66;
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(this.filePath));
        br.readLine();
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

            // use comma as separator
            String[] tempData = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
            Data.put(tempData[0], Double.parseDouble(tempData[1]));
            for(int i =0;i<=tempData[1].length();i++){
                //S++;
                if(((Double.parseDouble(tempData[1]))<x)){
                    System.out.println("A");

                }
```

How can I compare the double values that I got from `Double.parseDouble(tempData[1])` with the values `x`, `y` and `z`? I need to use logic like `if smaller than x print A, else if between x and y print B e lse print C` ....

Comment: "it doesnot work" - you can do better than that. Describe what you expected to happen, and what actually happened, in detail, with all error messages that you get. And do that in your question, not in a comment.

Comment: "it doesnot work" is not a description of a problem. You need to say *how* it does not work - doesn't compile, gives a runtime error, runs but gives unexpected output etc.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt great minds, clearly.

Comment: no help in this question ?

Comment: What sample data are you using?

Comment: double values from csv file ....

Answer (score 0):

> I need to use logic like `if smaller than x print A, else if between x
>   and y print B e lse print C` ....

Well, you can do almost exactly that. Just use a variable to keep the value:

```java
if (v < x) {
    System.out.println("A");
}
else if (v < y) {
    System.out.println("B");
}
else {
    System.out.println("C");
}
```

Adjust as needed.

Also, your `tempData` is a string array, `tempData[1]` is the second string in the array, and `tempData[1].length()` is the length of that string. I'm guessing you would rather want to go through all the values in the array, so your loop should probably look more like this:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < tempData.length; i++) {
    double v = Double.parseDouble(tempData[i]);
    // put your if statements here
}
```